# DirectX without ->Release()

Tags: c++, memory-management, com, directx

The most satisfying part of writing a DIY memory manager is structuring it so you can forget about [delete] (e.g. by bundling everything into a singly allocated/deallocated buffer).

The way DirectX handles object creation means that you can't simply cast void memory into the types you want to make (can you?) and you have to rely on COM (+ remembering to [Release] local memory in every destructor) instead. Is there any way to subvert this and convince DirectX to use my pointers?

Instead of:

```
ID3D12Thing* thng = DirectX::CreateThing();
...
thng->Release();
thng = nullptr;
```

I want:

```
ID3D12Thing* thng = DirectX::CreateThingAt(Allocator->AlignedAlloc(sizeof(ID3D12Thing));
...
[memory emptied during shutdown]
```

Comment: DirectX, including Direct3D and related APIs, have its own memory manager for creating its own objects. Including internal objects not exposed to you. So no, unlikely you can do this.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx

Comment: I doubt it's possible.
But if your main goal is less maintenance the obvious solution would be to use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter which does the `release()`. I can post an answer if you mean this.

Comment: @user2328447 yes, that could be interesting - anything that lets me centralise my deallocations is good :)

Comment: @selbie mmm :(. It sounds like I can fake it with smart pointers though?

Comment: @HansPassant Those would work, but I don't really like having hidden destructors at end-of-scope :/

Comment: Then you don't actually like smart pointers and RAII.  People get crucified in C++ land for saying stuff like that.

Comment: Heh, I guess it's what you're used to? I was taught [new] and [delete] when I started in C++. If I was taught [stackNew] and [stackDelete] I feel I'd end up preferring those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: Use a smart-pointer like [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).**

I'm a big fan of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, but neither of them really correctly handle COM objects such as Direct3D interfaces which have their own built-in reference counts. A better choice is to use WRL class `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` or the C++/WinRT class `winrt::com_ptr`.

> Some older coders might suggest the old ATL `CComPtr`, but the more modern `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` is a better choice.

Comment: Are the WinRT/WRL types equivalent? I'm not using winrt in my engine but I might reuse some of the code for a school thing and it'd be nice if they were interchangeable :).

Comment: WRL is a C++ template library and the ``ComPtr`` class is entirely C++ that works with plain old COM. You can use it in Win32 desktop apps on Windows 7 or UWP or Xbox One.  The C++/WinRT class is basically the same helper as ``ComPtr``, and you can use ``ComPtr`` in C++/WinRT projects if you want.

Comment: I am interested what the problems with `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are. They in my understanding allocate and release items exactly the same way as if they were allocated and released manually (which would obviously be ok) - but without the hassle. So I have to confess I don't understand the problem. I have already searched for it, but the results are pretty contradictory. Could you explain further (perhaps extend your answer)?

Comment: ``std::unique_ptr`` assumes is a single-owner model. With COM objects, you can have multiple shared owners.  ``std::shared_ptr`` uses it's own reference count (allocated externally), *not* the reference counting that is already part of the COM ``IUnknown`` so it's possible it's out of sync with the 'real' one. ``ComPtr`` does the right thing with respect to ``AddRef`` and ``Release``, as well as understanding how ``QueryInterface`` polymorphism of interfaces works.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn awesome, that makes things way easier ^_^

Comment: @user2328447 might have to move the tick here...can't get a better answer than a senior DX developer talking about modern COM-specific smart pointers :P

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn thanks, you are right. I have written an edit regarding this in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: This answer has been superseded by Chuck Walbourn's parallel answer.
While my answer is not completely wrong, after some investigation I'm pretty sure Chuck Walbourn's suggestion to use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` is the better choice (Please see also comment section under C.B.'s answer for reasons). **/Edit**

To my knowledge it is not possible to plant external memory on Direct X structures, since they are all created by Direct X itself.

Nevertheless, if the main goal is maintenance and safety, it is possible to define a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter which does the job of releasing.

```
struct DxDeleter {
    void operator() (IUnknown* _moribund) { if(_moribund) _moribund->Release(); }
};
typedef std::unique_ptr<ID3D11Buffer,DxDeleter>                 dx_buffer_ptr; 
typedef std::unique_ptr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView,DxDeleter>     dx_resource_ptr; 
typedef std::unique_ptr<ID3D11UnorderedAccessView,DxDeleter>    dx_access_ptr; 
...
```

The pointers then are simply assigned with e.g. `myUniqueDxBufferPtr.reset( myRawBufferPtr )` or similar.

This has the high benefit, that releases don't need to be tracked. It is a good way not only for Direct X, but for all kinds of external libraries, which need allocation and deallocation (for example, I use the same technique also for Freeimage and ffmpeg).

It is also possible to define `std::shared_ptr`s for resources, which are shared by multiple items (e.g. you could keep your device alive as long as any buffers exist). But this is to **handle with care** - in opposite of `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`s don't have the deleter as a template parameter, but as a ctor parameter - which makes it terribly easy to erroneously assign something with a missing deleter (leaks).

```
void g_dxDelete( IUnknown* _moribund ) {
    if( _moribund )
        _moribund->Release();
}

typedef std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Device> dx_device_shared;
inline dx_device_shared assignDevice( ID3D11Device* _device ) {
    return std::move( dx_device_shared( _device, g_dxDelete ) );
}
```

In that case you'd have to always be sure to assign the created device with `dx_device_shared myDevice = assignDevice(myRawDevicePtr)`, but NEVER with `dx_device_shared myDevice = myRawDevicePtr`.

Comment: Clever!
Thank you, this is (almost) exactly what I wanted :)
Could I write something to track each allocation as it happens and record the amount allocated? It'd be nice to threshold memory use somewhere and know EXACTLY how much memory I was going to use in each debug session.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to ask DirectX items about their real size - but if you find a way to do so, you could of course keep track of the memory.

Comment: Ahhhhh...ok. Time for another SO question :).
(I think I misread your comment, btw - I thought you'd taken control of allocations instead of deletions).

Comment: Sorry, don't know :(

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recently released a new library ([WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil)) for modern C++. It includes [a new com pointer type](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/WinRT-and-COM-wrappers):

```cpp
wil::com_ptr<ID3D12Thing> thng{DirectX::CreateThing())};
```